# CodeIgniter framework error in common.php file when i upload to cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter

It works fine in localhost but when i upload to cpanel it show this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/mydomain/inventory.mydomain.com/system/Common.php on line 45

in line 45 have a app_timezone method

```
function app_timezone(): string
{
    $config = config(App::class);
    return $config->appTimezone;
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Check your version of PHP running on the live site.

Comment: also after update php version 7.4 , its not work. But I don't know where the problem.